# How do I move a list's bullet point to the right side of the text?

Tags: html, css

The bullet image has to be on the right side of the text. Right now, it appears on the left side of the page, by default. How can I change this?

I have this CSS:

```
.landingpage ul{
list-style:none;
margin:0 0 1em 15px;
padding: 0;
list-style-position: inside;

}
.landingpage ul li{
line-height:1.3em;
margin: .25em 0;
padding: 0 0 0 15px;
background:url(../images/star.png) no-repeat 0 4px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.landingpage li ul{
margin:0 0 0 30px;
list-style:disc;
}
 .landingpage li ul li{
padding-right:0;
background:none;
}

/* Holly Hack to fix ie6 li bg */
/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html li{height: 1%;}
/* End hide from IE-mac */

@media print{
.landingpage ul {
list-style:disc;
margin-right:30px;
}
 .landingpage ul li {
padding-right:0px;
background:none;
}
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="landingpage">
<ul >
<li>מפחד מהמלחמה</li>
</div>

</ul>
```

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TrLQ4/ of OP post. (I didn't alter the code in any way, it was a C&P job)

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Efvx4/?

Comment: yes but text has to be to the right side of the screen

Comment: Could you display the image? Because the link for the image does not show anything.

Comment: Like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Efvx4/1/)?

Comment: i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you don't have a bullet point is because of `list-style: none;`

Remove `list-style: none;` from `.landingpage ul` and, if you wish to, you can add `direction: rtl;` to have the list appear on the right side of the screen instead of the left.

```
.landingpage ul{
    margin:0 0 1em 15px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-position: inside;
    /* direction: rtl; */
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/yv3ud/)**

Comment: I'm assuming his bullet point is the star image "background", and that's why the standard bullet is hidden. But yes, that's how you'd do it with a normal bullet. I'm guessing the more modern `list-style-image` is what you'd want to use for a custom bullet these days, but I don't know what browser support is like...

Comment: direction: rtl; is awesome. Never ran into it before. Thanks!

Comment: @tempranova A necessary property for languages that read right-to-left!

Answer (score 1):

Try the below css

CSS

```
li{
direction:rtl;
}
ul{
  list-style-position:inside;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/V88UY/)